# Spring @Autowired property is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I apologize if this question has already been asked or answered somewhere. I have a sample code, which is not working as intended. Spring annotation `@Autowired` is not working. Whereas in the same setup I have `@Inject` working with Weld 1.1.0 and Tomcat 6.

**WorkTester.java**

```
  //1. Do I need to mark some class as component to wire a property in that class? Intellij 
  //always warns if I don't.
  @Component
    public class WorkTester {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("work")
        private Work work;
        //2. There is a bean in MVC context with name work. Why doesn't it work?

        public void testWork() {
            System.out.println("Work : " + work);
        }

        public Work getWork() {
            return work;
        }

        //2. If there is a bean called 'work' in any of the contexts, do I need setters?
        public void setWork(Work work) {
            this.work = work;
        }
    }
```

**WorkImpl.java**

```
public class WorkImpl implements Work {

    @Override
    public void doWork(String task) {
        System.out.println("Yahoo! " + task);
    }
}
```

I have `applicationContext.xml`, which is empty. My `dispatcher-servet.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.brs.in"/>

    <bean id="work" class="com.brs.in.WorkImpl"/>
</beans>
```

My **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.brs.in.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

As mentioned in the comments(Questions 1, 2, 3) in the first snippet of code, can anyone answer why autowiring is not working?

**Entry Point:**

This is the sample servlet where I am calling the method causing `NullPointerException`:

```
    @Inject
    private Work worker;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Worker has been injected " + ((worker != null)));

        worker.doWork(1, 2);//No Problem

        new WorkTester().testWork();//Causing trouble

    }
```

Comment: You said it's: not working as intended. What actually happens?

Comment: @benji work is always null.

Comment: Have you provided <context:annotation-config>

Comment: @kamoor1982 context-component scan is there.

Comment: <bean id="work" class="com.brs.in.WorkImpl" autowire="byName"/> Try this

Comment: Show the class where you're calling `getWork()`.

Comment: Don't expect a servlet container managed object to be processed as a bean by Spring.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry. I didn't get you. The bean is scoped to MVC servlet right?

Comment: I might have close prematurely with that duplicate. A servlet instance is managed by the servlet container, not be Spring. Nothing will be injected. Look up how to integrate or inject beans into servlets with Spring. The duplicate is more about the `// causing trouble`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I actually don't even see logs by spring that it has instantiated a bean called work in an contexts during startup. Can you kindly explain why this is happening? I have correct web.xml right?

Comment: No, it's a duplicate. The manual instantiation is the one with the problem.

Answer (score -1):

include this to your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` `<context:annotation-config/>`  @Autowired annotation alone is not enough you need to enable it.  [Ref.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.brs.in"/>` is used to scan those controller as far as i know . but still im not sure :)

i just notice about how you create your dispatcher on your `web.xml` it should be like this.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

from spec.

> The load-on-startup element indicates that this servlet should be
>   loaded (instantiated and have its init() called) on the startup of the
>   web application. The optional contents of these element must be an
>   integer indicating the order in which the servlet should be loaded. If
>   the value is a negative integer, or the element is not present, the
>   container is free to load the servlet whenever it chooses. If the
>   value is a positive 128 integer or 0, the container must load and
>   initialize the servlet as the application is deployed. The container
>   must guarantee that servlets marked with lower integers are loaded
>   before servlets marked with higher integers. The container may choose
>   the order of loading of servlets with the same load-on-start-up value.

Comment: No. Use. I tried the same. Still property work is null.

Comment: component-scan is super set of annotation config, I think

Comment: try to delete the `@Qualifier("work")` tho im not sure about it. just a hunch

Comment: or try to delete this `<context:component-scan base-package="com.brs.in"/>` and replace with this `<context:annotation-config/>`

Comment: Just tried the same. Not working. May be it's not the issue. Even if we don't configure params files will be searched for. The issue is why MVC beans not created?

Comment: I didn't down vote the ans

Comment: i know sir :) but someone downvoted it. for @misterDownVoter please explain first.

Comment: 1. Add <context:component-scan> in your application context.  2. Add this to your web.xml   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/pathTo/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>